# Windows 8.1 disabling touchpad with USB mouse but does not persist

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

To disable my touchpad on my Lenovo Z500 when using a mouse (which is most of the time for me) I do the following:

Control Panel > Mouse > ELAN

And tick: 'Disable when external USB pointing device plug in'

(See attached image for confirmation of dialog/bad English.)

My problem is that this preference does not persist. Once I reboot my laptop then the touchpad is active again and I have to return to the dialog and untick/re-tick the preference to disable it.

Also this preference overrides the function key (FN+F6) to toggle the touchpad.

I do occasionally use the laptop without a mouse, so I don't want to permanent disable it, I just want the preference to stick! Drivers are fully up to date going by what's available from Lenovo's downloads.

[image]

Comment: Have you reported the problem to Lenovo?  There is likely a registry key that handles this behavior, if thats the case, have you found it?  You might be able to get around this problem by using something like Autohotkey.  Would not resolve it not being persistant but would prevent you having to launch the mouse properties everytime you restart.

Comment: No, I've not reported it to Lenovo. I may do later. Since the FN+F6 shortcut works fine when the Disable feature is not ticked, I'll probably fall back on that.